# Leitura de headers em WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um código que faz um post para uma url e adiciona alguns parâmetros ao Header da requisição

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
req.Headers.Add("X-ICM-API-Authorization", token);
```

Como faço o código para ler estes parâmetros que estão no header no Web API?

Comment: você faz a requisição numa URL local ou externa? pode colocar os códigos além desse?

Comment: Olá virgilio, o que preciso é fazer a codificação do lado do server para responder a esta solicitação, e preciso ler o X-ICM-API-Authorization que foii enviado no Headers

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api ou http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1223/secure-aspnet-web-api-using-tokens-owin-angularjs ??? seria um desses links? !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se seu controller herda de `ApiController`, você pode recuperar os *headers* da requisição através da propriedade `Request`, que por sua vez possui uma propriedade [`Headers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.headers(v=vs.118).aspx).

No caso especifico de autenticação/autorização sugiro usar um [*Message Handler*](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers).